Azure DevOps pipeline trigger doesn't work
I want to create a yaml pipeline which will be automatically triggered when there are new changes in some specific branches. However the trigger doesn't work at all. Yaml file is in branch A. Can someone help me, please?
trigger:
branches:
include:
- B
- C
I setup a default branch for A branch, also enabled continuous integration in Triggers settings


Yaml file is in branch A.  trigger: branches: include: - B - C

You need to copy the yaml file to both branch B and C.
Simply create Pull Requests to merge the source from A to B and C. Once this is done, the CI trigger will work as expected.

@Gabriela Please also check to see if there's an UI trigger setting overwitted the YAML one. See FAQ - Failing triggers to troubleshoot the issue.
